# undefined reference to `ros::init (correct CMakeLists.txt)

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suddenly my caktin build does not work anymore.

Linking seem to fail. But the project works on other computers (all Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic).

I already tried:

- setting up a new catkin ws
- reinstalling ros completely
- reinstall catkin
- testing other nodes / packages

The linking error occurs in every package now. Maybe anyone can help.

Here is e.gcthe beginner_tutorials project:
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)
## Declare ROS messages and services
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package

catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

# %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- %Tag(FULLTEXT,-1)% -->
<package>
  <!-- %Tag(NAME)% -->
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <!-- %EndTag(NAME)% -->
  <!-- %Tag(VERSION)% -->
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <!-- %EndTag(VERSION)% -->
  <!-- %Tag(DESC)% -->
  <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>
  <!-- %EndTag(DESC)% -->

  <!-- %Tag(MAINTAINER)% -->
  <maintainer email="you@yourdomain.tld">Your Name</maintainer>
  <!-- %EndTag(MAINTAINER)% -->
  <!-- %Tag(LICENSE)% -->
  <license>BSD</license>
  <!-- %EndTag(LICENSE)% -->
  <!-- %Tag(URLS)% -->
  <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/beginner_tutorials</url>
  <!-- %EndTag(URLS)% -->
  <!-- %Tag(AUTHORS)% -->
  <author email="you@yourdomain.tld">Jane Doe</author>
  <!-- %EndTag(AUTHORS)% -->

  <!-- %Tag(DEPS)% -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>

  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <!-- %EndTag(DEPS)% -->

  <!-- %Tag(EXPORT)% -->
  <!-- %EndTag(EXPORT)% -->
</package>
<!-- %EndTag(FULLTEXT)% -->
```

talker.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::String msg;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello world " << count;
    msg.data = ss.str();

    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

    chatter_pub.publish(msg);

    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/a6a720ede82e489358d01ed5e403fe40

The libs in /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/ look all fine. But not sure what I can do!

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244554/undefined-reference-to-%60ros::init-(correct-cmakelists.txt)/) by [miseryindevice](https://answers.ros.org/users/28078/miseryindevice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you changed your default compiler recently, or made C++11 mode the default? The ROS binaries are compiled with the older C++ library, and this makes them incompatible with code compiled with the C++11 libraries.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basti.hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28078/basti.hunter/) on 2016-09-27**:
Yes, I recently updated to gcc 5.4.0 for some other program. But the 4.9.4 is still on my system. How can I tell catkin to use the old one?
BUT: I jsut (ugly for my other settings) uninstalled gcc 5.4.0 and reinstalled 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.9' --> Not ros builds again. Thanks!!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-27**:
@miseryindevice: if you feel @ahendrix's answer answered your question, could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of it? Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-27**:
As to choosing a compiler for Catkin: look into the 'alternatives' tool on Ubuntu, or use the `CXX` and `CC` environment variables.

Note that this is not Catkin specific: when searching for documentation/hints, leave 'catkin' out of your queries.